# How can I check the network usage of my Monero node?

Tags: monerod, full-node, network

I would like to check the network use of my Monero node (daemon). I would like to see the average upload and download speeds, and I would like to see the total amount of data (eg: in MB, GB, TB) that has been transferred. How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with the 0.14.1 (April 2019) update. rbrunner created [new code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/5327) that allows users to see global traffic stats.

While monerod (the node software) is running, you can type the following command in the terminal:

`print_net_stats`

This will display information on how much data was transferred and the average upload and download speeds, among other useful network connectivity information. Here is an example output:

```
Received 7354450 bytes (7.01 MB) in 4682 packets, average 1.39 kB/s = 0.02% of the limit of 8.00 MB/s
Sent 49976456 bytes (47.66 MB) in 4705 packets, average 9.47 kB/s = 0.46% of the limit of 2.00 MB/s
```

Comment: You can also use the existing command `print_cn` which gives you `Recv/Sent (inactive,sec)` per connected peer.